# Python 3, VS code, and utf-8 is producing an error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code and the interpreter is Python 3.8.3

When I'm doing the following :

```
print("é")
```

I got the following error :

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file
```

If I change my code for :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print("é")
```

It works as expected. I understand that the coding: utf-8 should be useless in python3. It's like despite picking a Python3 interpreter, it's running on Python2. What could be the source of the issue ?

Comment: The magic coding comment is for declaring the encoding of the *source*.  The error is generated because you typed a character that Python can't read from the console.

Comment: VS code seems to be configured for Python 2. Use PyCharm instead ;-)

Comment: Add this to `settings.json` `"files.encoding": "utf8",` All you files will be saved in that format. Regarding python no idea :D

Comment: after investigation, if I do a print(sys.version), the output is python 2.7.15. I don't get why VS Studio don't use the right interpreter

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution :

- Make sure the interpreter path in your json file is right
- Add the following parameter :

  "code-runner.executorMap.python": "python3 -u"

I don't know if it should have been there at the beginning, but it now runs on the correct Python version.